# Derivation of numerical scheme for linear transport equation on a variable stencil

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

The question is about automatica derivation of coefficients of numerical scheme  on a variable stencil.

So, lets consider 1d transport equation
\begin{equation}
(1)\qquad u_t+u_x=0.
\end{equation}
To discretize (1), let's consider the following stencil:
\begin{equation}
(2)\qquad (t^{n+1},x_{j-1}),\,(t^{n},x_{j-1}),\,(t^{n},x_{j}).
\end{equation}
Then, let's consider the following approximation of (1) on (2):
$$
(3)\qquad u_j^{n+1} = a_1u_{j-1}^n+a_2u_j^n,
$$
where $a_1,\,a_2$ to be determined by Taylor series expansion.

My first step seems to be as follows:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0
approx = Series[u[x, t + τ], {t, 0, 2}] - 
         (a1 Series[u[x - h, t], {x, 0, 2}] + 
          a2 Series[u[x, t], {x, 0, 2}])
```

The question is how to derive differential consequence from (1) to obtain system of two equation on $a_i,\,i=1,2$?

Comment: So what is the question? And do you want to do this with the computing software *Mathematica*? If so, please explain what specifically you are having difficulties with in implementing your algorithm in *Mathematica*. If not, your question belongs elsewhere, perhaps [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Sure, edited just now.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Do you want to use *Mathematica* to show that the discretization of Eq. 1 results in Eq. 3, and as a consequence derive what $a_1$ and $a_2$ should be?

Comment: I guess, my question is the second one. Means, that we hold stencil (2) and approximation (3), consequently. The question is how to obtain $a_1,\,a_2$ by unknow coefficient method with the usage of differential consequences of (1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I go about doing this type of algebra with *Mathematica*:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0;
```

First, expand the function `u[x, t + dt]` to first order in `dt` around `0` and the function `u[x -h, t]` to first order in `h` around `0`:

```
eqn1 = u[x, t + dt] == Series[u[x, t + dt], {dt, 0, 1}] // Normal
eqn2 = u[x - h, t] == Series[u[x - h, t], {h, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

[image]

We want to eliminate the partial derivatives, so we solve for them:

```
sols = First@Solve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {D[u[x, t], t], D[u[x, t], x]}]
```

[image]

Finally, we use the fact that the partial derivatives are negative each other because of the original differential equation to eliminate them from the equation:

```
differenceEquation = eqn /. sols
```

[image]

Finally, we solve for the next time step and collect terms on the right hand side

```
Collect[Equal @@ Solve[differenceEquation, u[x, dt + t]][[1, 1]], u[x, t]]
```

[image]

From there, you can read off `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: Ok, but how such derivation could be adopted on the following scheme, for example,
$$
u_j^{n+1} = a_1u_{j-1}^n + a_2 u_{j}^n + a_3 u_{j+1}^n, \quad \text{(Lax-Wendroff scheme)}
$$
or
$$
u_j^{n+1} = a_1u_{j-1}^n + a_2 u_{j}^n + a_3 u_{j+1}^n + a_4 u_{j+2}^n?
$$

Comment: @olekravchenko. I can't think of a way of *automating* derivations of the different schemes, because they use different choices for the finite-difference approximations of the derivatives. I would just generalize what I did above, but in general my method requires knowledge of how the derivation is done in the first place. Nonetheless, in the meantime, I'll think on it. You *might* consider asking a new question about how to automate the derivation of *general* schemes on *general* stencils. I just answered this question originally assuming that all you wanted was the particular one shown.

Comment: In fact I wrote _on a variable stencil_ to ask question in more wide sence. Anyway, let me follow your advice and ask new question about automatical derivation on quite general stencil.