# How to obtain differential consequences of linear transport equation automatically?

Tags: expression-construction, automation

**Motivation**

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/derivation-of-numerical-scheme-for-linear-transport-equation-on-a-variable-stenc) I've asked how to derive coefficients of numerical approximation of the linear transport equation 
$$
u_t + u_x = 0,
\tag{1}
$$ 
on a fixed 3-point stencil automatically and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100261/how-to-derive-finite-difference-scheme-automatically-on-a-quite-general-stencil) I've asked about automatical derivation on general m-point stencil as well.

In the present question I would like to ask about automatical way of derivation of the following differential consequences (DC) of (1):
\begin{align}
u_t &= -u_x, \\
u_{tx} &= -u_{xx}, \\
u_{tt} &= -u_{xt} = u_{xx}, \\
u_{txx} &= - u_{xxx}, \\
u_{ttt} &= -u_{xtt} = u_{xxt} = -u_{xxx}, \\
&\ldots
\tag{2}
\end{align}

I need DC (2), cause I need to consider the following approximation
$$
u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n - \tau\,u_x.
\tag{3}
$$

DC (2) are applied in expansion of $u_j^{n+1}$ around $(x_j,t^n)$ node as follows:
\begin{align}
& u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n + \tau\bigl(u_t\bigr)_j^n + \frac{\tau^2}{2!}\bigl(u_{tt}\bigr)_j^n + \frac{\tau^3}{3!}\bigl(u_{ttt}\bigr)_j^n + O(\tau^4) = \\
=\,& u_j^n - \tau\bigl(u_x\bigr)_j^n + \frac{\tau^2}{2!}\bigl(u_{xx}\bigr)_j^n - \frac{\tau^3}{3!}\bigl(u_{xxx}\bigr)_j^n + O(h^4).
\tag{4}
\end{align}

**WM code**

I've made the following semi-analytic solution.

```
    {
     eq = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0,
     eqdc01 = D[eq, t],
     eqdc02 = D[eq, t, t],
     eqdc03 = D[eq, x],
     sol00 = Solve[eq, D[u[x, t], t]] // First,
     sol01 = Solve[eqdc01, D[u[x, t], {x, 0}, {t, 2}]] // First,
     sol02 = Solve[eqdc03, D[u[x, t], {x, 1}, {t, 1}]] // First,
     sol03 = Solve[eqdc02, D[u[x, t], {x, 1}, {t, 2}]] // First,
     sol04 = Solve[eqdc02, D[u[x, t], {x, 0}, {t, 3}]] // First,
     sol05 = D[sol02, {t, 1}],
     sol06 = D[sol00, {x, 2}],
     sol07 = sol05 /. sol06,
     sol08 = sol04 /. sol07
    } // Column
```

[image: Out2]

```
    {
     se01 = Series[u[x, t + \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, 3}] // Normal,
     lhs = se01 /. sol00 /. sol01 /. sol02 /. sol08 // Normal,
     rhs = Sum[
     Subscript[a, 
     i] (Series[u[x + i h, t], {h, 0, 3}] // Normal), {i, -1, 2, 1}]
    } // Column
```

[image]

**Question**

The question is how to derive DC (2) automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility that is relatively general.

```
Clear[diffCons]
diffCons[eq_Equal, level_Integer /; level == 0] := Reduce@eq
diffCons[eq_Equal, level_Integer /; level >= 1] :=
  Reduce@Module[
   {variables = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[eq, Derivative[__][_][x__] :> x, Infinity]}
   , D[eq, Sequence @@ Transpose@{variables, #}] & /@ Select[Tuples[Reverse@Range[0, level], Length@variables], Plus @@ # == level &]
  ]
```

Given

```
eq = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0
```

we choose a `level`. Level 0 just spits back the equation, but `Reduce`d:

```
diffCons[eq, 0]
(* {Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == -Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]} *)
```

Level 1 means take all first derivatives of the equation:

```
diffCons[eq, 1]
(* Derivative[u][1, 1][x, t] == -Derivative[u][2, 0][x, t] && Derivative[u][0, 2][x, t] == -Derivative[u][2, 0][x, t] *)
```

And so on.

---

If you want `Rule`s instead, use this modified version of the function:

```
Clear[diffConsRule]
diffConsRule[eq_Equal, level_Integer /; level == 0] := {Rule @@ Reduce@eq}
diffConsRule[eq_Equal, level_Integer /; level >= 1] :=
  Rule@@@List@@Reduce@Module[
   {variables = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[eq, Derivative[__][_][x__] :> x, Infinity]}
   , D[eq, Sequence @@ Transpose@{variables, #}] & /@ Select[Tuples[Reverse@Range[0, level], Length@variables], Plus @@ # == level &]
  ]
```

In this case,

```
diffConsRule[eq, 0]
(* {Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] -> -Derivative[1, 0][u][x, t]} *)
```

and

```
diffConsRule[eq, 1]
(* {Derivative[u][1, 1][x, t] -> -Derivative[u][2, 0][x, t], Derivative[u][0, 2][x, t] -> Derivative[u][2, 0][x, t]} *)
```

---

The function `diffCons` is not tested *too* well, but is *should* work for a general partial differential equation of any number of variables.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I suppose, that is an aswer on my question and it will take some time to understand such an elegant code from my side.

Comment: @olekravchenko. In my opinion, the code is brute-forced and not very elegant at all, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Bye the way, how could I use notification on a previous commenter? In my case '@march' disapear everytime.

Comment: @olekravchenko. If you are commenting below a question or answer, the person who wrote that question or answer is automatically notified, so you don't need too use the @ unless you are trying to talk to someone who is not the author of the question/answer you are commenting on.

Comment: Anyway, I wasn't able to use @ couple of times ago.

I could put '@march' in the end of my reply only.

Comment: @olekravchenko. Don't know what the problem could be, then.